# What's The difference between *(a[1]) and *(*a+1) in C?

Tags: c, pointers

It seems that they're different when I debug them in gdb.

```
 (gdb) p order[1]
 $16 = (struct order_s *) 0x746440
 (gdb) p *order+1
 $17 = (struct order_s *) 0x746430
 (gdb) p *order
 $18 = (struct order_s *) 0x746420
```

What's the difference between *a[1] and *(*a+1) in C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Order of operations. `a[1]` is the same as `*(a+1)`. So, `*a[1]` is the same as `*(*(a+1))`. If you have `*(*a+1)` then you are actually doing `*(a[0]+1)`.